# 1-я мировая/Мировая война

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Наверное, с маленькой: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1-%D1%8F+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C+1-%D1%8F+%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3. Просто я подумал, что, может быть, это как вот это: *Восьмое марта – 8 Марта.*

`Что произошло в 1-й мировой войне?`

`Что произошло в 1-й Мировой войне?`

Comment: Не найти ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Что произошло в **Первой** мировой войне?*

**[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)**

Запись ***1-я мировая война*** не имеет смысла, так как неясно значение слова "мировая".

А с вариантом ***Восьмое марта – 8 Марта***  все нормально, здесь **устойчивое** словосочетание в названии праздника.